# Best way to calculate responsive font size in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout, responsive

Based on research from google.
I found three ways to calculate the responsive font size.

Here 414 refers to device width
720 refers to device height
50 refers to font size value
Approach 1:
responsivefontSize =50(input value of font) * Media query.width/414

Approach 2:
responsivefontSize=(50/720)*MediaQuery.height

Approach 3:
responsivefontSize = (MediaQuery.height/100)*50

Suggest me best way to calculate the responsive font size for different devices in flutter.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to scale text based on the width of a container or a device, try wrapping your text field in a FittedBox

Comment: Is this useful https://pub.dev/packages/sizer/example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**FIRST METHOD:**
My personal favorite and what I can recommend is to use the "responsive_framework" package. You just wrap your Widget with a few lines of code and your whole project autoscales itself.

CLARIFICATION: This package resizes everything in your projecty, not only the text size.

package: https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework

How to implement it:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, widget) => ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
          BouncingScrollWrapper.builder(context, widget),
          maxWidth: 1200,
          minWidth: 450,
          defaultScale: true,
          breakpoints: [
            ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(450, name: MOBILE),
            ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
            ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: TABLET),
            ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoscale(1200, name: DESKTOP),
            ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(2460, name: "4K"),
          ],
          background: Container(color: Color(0xFF7E2323))),
      home: MyWidget()));
```

And that's it. you can just copy paste it like that to your project.
Also: Sometimes you want to change autoScale with resize and vice versa.

**SECOND METHOD**:
another package which should work fine for you is the sizer package which allows you to write fontsizes like this:

```
fontSize: 15.0.sp
```

this will automatically change the fontsize on different screen sizes.

package: https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

I hope this helps you out!
:)

Comment: Sizer package seems better because it also has font size adjustment.Is my opinion is correct?

Comment: Well my favorite is still the first package because I like it how it scales everything according to the screen size. But just use what works best for you. (sry for the late answer :) )

Comment: I try to understand the responsive framework package but some of concepts are confusion.Could you please suggest me some links or blogs or sample to understand this package

Comment: I had the same problem because I couldnt find any good documentations. I just tested it out myself and got it to work at the end but I can show you how I use it for sure. Just take a look at my answer again :)

Comment: @Mesota22 I am trying reponsive_framework, and I can't get the text in a stack with a background image to rescale or resize. Is any wrapping widget needed to have responsive text?

Comment: Hm when I used that package I haven't had an issue like that, it should be enough to just do what I wrote in my answer. I am sorry I can't help you out there :(

Comment: The Sizer package doesn't work on the web but is a solid option if you use any other platform.